# JQuery Ajax call refused by Django server in google compute engine. net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: jquery, django, rest, google-cloud-platform

I have a Django web server with REST API. Front end Ajax is implemented with JQuery. All works in local Mac and Ubuntu.

When deployed in google computer engine, web page showed up and subsequence Ajax call failed with error:

net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

This application does not have cross domain API calls. It's simply web page ajax call to the same web server.

Firewall rule allow TCP:8000

```
Ingress http-server IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0  tcp:8000   Allow 1000  default
```

I also confirmed that Ajax call never reached the server side. It's like refused by google compute engine.

What GCP configuration is missing?

Comment: mind sharing the Ajax call? did you add an `error: function (xhr, ...` in your Ajax call? what is the error message? What type of call is that? PUT, GET, POST?

Comment: Has .fail(function(data) {} . data.responseText=''. Ajax call is POST.

Comment: Found issue: port should be specified after domain (or ip) depending how server started. If python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000, port should be used in ajax call. If start server in nginx, no port is needed.